# django permissions to restrict view based on groups

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

I currently have an order management app. But the team I am creating this for has two departments the office and the factory who'll be using the same app but with each team having access to what they need. I'm confused if I should create two different apps to login into the same system  (but that would redundant code) or if there's any other way I can set permissions. I have tried using the django admin permissions and they don't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

you can create different html pages for different teams like office team have their own html page and factory team have different html page .

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username=request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                if user.is_admin:
                    login(request,user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('adminpage'))
                    #return render(request,'admin.html')
                else:
                    login(request,user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('userpage'))
                    #return render(request,'user.html')
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('Account not active')
        else:
            #message={"info":"someone tried to login and failed! ","details":"username :{} and password: {}".format(username,password)}
            return HttpResponse("someone tried to login and failed ! <br />details: <br />username: {} <br /> password:{} ".format(username,password))
    else:
        return render(request,'login.html')
```

you can create models with specified role as active according to condition.(you can create radio button for factory and office and according to radio button you models code work.

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address',max_length=255,unique=True,)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_agent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

choices are :

```
USER_CHOICES = (
   ('is_admin','ADMIN'),
   ('is_agent', 'AGENT')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the same authentication page for both users and staff and redirect them to the same page, (suppose the `dashboard` ). Now you can add a link in the dashboard which is visible only if the logged in user is a superuser. The link would redirect to an admin interface.
The dashboard could be something common for both users.
Hope this helps.